# Why is command cascade delete not working in my code

Tags: sql-server

Hello Can somebody check as why cascade delete option is not working when I delete record from CustomerOrder it still stays in Customer?

```
Create database demodb 
GO
Use demodb 
GO



Create table dbo.Customer
(
CustomerID int identity(1,1) primary key,
CustomerName nvarchar(30) not null
);
GO



Insert into dbo.Customer
Values ('Mario Saric'), ('Maja Majic');


Create Table dbo.CustomerOrder(
CustomerOrderID int identity(1001,1) primary key,
CustomerID int not null,
OrderAmount decimal(4,2));
GO

Select * from dbo.Customer


insert into dbo.CustomerOrder
values(1, 44.22), (2, 33.33);



insert into dbo.CustomerOrder
values(5, 42.22);


Delete from Customer
Where CustomerID=1;



Alter Table dbo.CustomerOrder
Drop Constraint FK__CustomerO__Custo__164452B1;
GO

Alter Table dbo.CustomerOrder
Add Constraint FK_CustomerOrder_Customer 
foreign Key (CustomerID)
References dbo.Customer (CustomerID)
On delete cascade;
GO

Select * From CustomerOrder;


Delete from dbo.CustomerOrder
where CustomerID = 2;

Select * From dbo.CustomerOrder;

Select * From dbo.Customer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting from the CustomerOrder table, try deleting from the Customer table.

Customer Order is really the child table.  For example, you could have a customer that cancels an order, in which case you would want to delete just that order from the CustomerOrder table.

If you wanted to delete a customer, you would also want to delete all their orders.  This is what Cascade Delete is for.  Delete from Customer would also remove their customer orders.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!